# kotlin division of nullable arguments

Tags: kotlin

Suppose, I have a class of the following structure

```
class Test {
  var a: Double? = null
  var b: Double? = null;
  var c: Double? = null;
}
```

`a` and `b` are set somewhere else, and `c` should be calculated as `a / b` or `null` if at least one of the arguments is `null`. Is there an easy way to achieve this in Kotlin?

I has to do it the following way now:

```
fun calculateValues() {
  ...
  val a = test.a
  val b = test.b
  if (a != null && b != null) 
    test.c = a / b
  ...
}
```

Comment: Do you retrieve `c` in the same code/method you pass `a` and `b`?

Comment: Be sure b is not equals to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test.apply {
    c = if (a==null || b==null) null else a/b
}
```

Of course that can be included as a getter of c (which in turn avoids storing c as a field):

```
class Test {
  var a: Double? = null
  var b: Double? = null
  var c: Double? = null
    get() = if (a==null || b==null) null else a/b
}
```

If Test is not a class of yours, you can always use an extension function:

```
fun Test.updateC() {
  c = if (a==null || b==null) null else a/b
}
```

and that can then be called on a Test instance just like any other function of the Test class: `test.updateC()`

If you need to make sure about nullability at the time of computing a/b, you should use temporary variables as indicated in @Joshua answer below. Or also read the following Kotlin discussion: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-null-check-for-multiple-nullable-vars/1946/11 and ticket:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20294

I especially like the reusable solution with a function:

```
fun notNull(vararg args: Any?, action: () -> Unit) {
    when {
        args.filterNotNull().size == args.size -> action()
    }
}
```

which can be used then as:

```
c = null
notNull(a, b) { c = a/b }
```

Comment: Note that checking `a == null` and `b == null` does **NOT** guarantee that  cannot be null when `a/b`. The IDE should have warned you about they are mutable. Ever time you access them does not guarantee the value are the same.

Comment: Linked to your answer for that case. See also: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-null-check-for-multiple-nullable-vars/1946/11

Answer (score 2):

```
class Test {
    var a: Double? = null
    var b: Double? = null
    val c: Double? // It should be val as it is readonly
        get() {
            // This is need as a & b are mutable
            val dividend = a
            val divisor = b
            if (dividend == null || divisor == null)
                return null
            return dividend / divisor
        }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted - the class is supposed to only hold data, not business logic, and still 7 extra lines of code

Comment: @ekaerovets If `c` is always calculate from `a` and `b` only, then it should be considered as one of the data. Also, if you want to reduce number of line, the best solution is not using nullable.

Comment: that's customer data, and they can be easily nullable. I don't want to calculate c in the class itself because there are some fields, that require data from another classes - so I prefer to calculate all the fields of class Test  in a separate service. Too bad the language design doesn't allow things like /?

Comment: @ekaerovets You can use extension like `val Test.c` or `fun Test.c()`

Answer (score 0):

As the logic is outside of `Test` class I don't find the problem of checking nullability before making the operation. Anyway, `if else` is also an expressión in Kotlin so you could do the following:

```
val a = test.a
val b = test.b
t.c = if (a != null && b != null) a / b else null
```

Comment: That's what I do now. The problem is that a pretty simple operation requires 2 extra variables and 3 lines of code.